# Adding dashboard widgets to show - custom post type stats, information from other plugins

Tags: widgets, dashboard

I have a website and i need to be able to edit the dashboard widgets so it shows relevant information to the website.

At the moment all that is showing is the right now widget. Inside this widget, i don't need the discussion section nor do i need posts and tags. What i do need is custom post types, for example products and news. So it would say products then how many products there are, like it does with pages.

It would also be great if you could show information from other plugins. For example i'm using a plugin called [Support Ticket Center](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/zingiri-tickets/), it would be great if you could show how many open support tickets there are and how many have been closed and things.

Are there any plugins that can do this kind of customization? Or is it more complicated?

Thanks

**EDIT**:
I've tried adding the following code to my functions.php file. It sort of works but the output is adding a lot of other divs and things. I don't understand where they are coming from.

```
    // wp_dashboard_setup is the action hook
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'mycustom_dashboard_stats');

// add dashboard widget
function mycustom_dashboard_stats() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget('site_stat_widget', 'Site Stats','wp_dashboard_custom_post_types');
}

function wp_dashboard_custom_post_types() {
    global $wp_registered_sidebars;

    $num_posts = wp_count_posts( 'Product' );


    echo "\n\t".'<div class="table table_content">';
    echo "\n\t".'<p class="sub">' . __('Content') . '</p>'."\n\t".'<table>';
    echo "\n\t".'<tr class="first">';

    // Posts
    $num = number_format_i18n( $num_posts->publish );
    $text = _n( 'Product', 'Products', intval($num_posts->publish) );
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
        $num = "<a href='edit.php'>$num</a>";
        $text = "<a href='edit.php'>$text</a>";
    }
    echo '<td class="first b b-products">' . $num . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="t products">' . $text . '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
}
```

This is the html code it is outputting.

```
<div class="table table_content">
<p class="sub">Content</p>
<div class="postbox-container" style="width:49%;">
<div class="postbox-container" style="display:none;width:49%;">
<div class="postbox-container" style="display:none;width:49%;">
<p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<table>
</div>
```

This will output 'Content' then a huge gap then the number of products. I don't know why it's inserting all of the clear divs and things.

How do i get it to output the html the same as the 'Right Now' widget, so it display properly and would also use the same css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a little more fancy, but this should get you started.

```
add_action( 'right_now_content_table_end', 'wpse_3809');
function wpse_3809() {
    $types = get_post_types( array( '_builtin' => false ) );
    foreach( $types as $type ) :
        $num_posts = wp_count_posts( $type );
        $num = number_format_i18n( $num_posts->publish );
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="first b b_<?php echo $type; ?>">
                <a href="edit.php?post_type=<?php echo $type; ?>"><?php echo $num; ?></a>
            </td>
            <td class="t <?php echo $type; ?>">
                <a href="edit.php?post_type=<?php echo $type; ?>"><?php echo $type; ?></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    endforeach;
}
```

**Edit:**
The code for the "Right Now" dashboard widget can be found in /wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php the function is `wp_dashboard_right_now`. Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a filter that will allow you to remove post, page, categories, tags, or comments. If you want to remove them, you can use JavaScript to remove the elements from the DOM or you *might* be able to hide them with CSS (if there is a CSS parent selector?). Alternatively, you could copy the code and remove / add anything you want. If you don't want to list all your custom post types, remove the `get_post_types` and foreach loop, and replace `$type` with the custom post type name.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to make it so i can list which post types i want to display instead of listing all of them. So i can remove posts, but add products and any others i want to add.

Comment: Not possible to remove post, page, categories, tags, or comments. See edit for more information.

Comment: How about if i don't display the right now widget and make a new widget displaying only the custom post types i want (product, News). That way i'm not removing post, page, categories, tags or comments.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, use the `wp_dashboard_right_now` code as a starting point.

Comment: I've updated the question with some code that i have tried, however it's not quite working.

Answer (score 0):

@v0idless code is work fine but
please use it for best result

//$types = get_post_types( array( '_builtin' => false ) );

```
$types = get_post_types( array( '_builtin' => false,'public'   => true ) );
```